# Open cover running coverage for xunit.runner.utility.dotnet

Tags: .net-core, code-coverage, opencover

No matter what target I pick, the output from Open Cover is always showing assemblies from (Coverage.xml):

```
<ModulePath>C:\Users\XXX\.nuget\packages\xunit.runner.utility\2.2.0-beta2-build3300\lib\netstandard1.1\xunit.runner.utility.dotnet.dll</ModulePath>
<ModuleTime>2016-06-27T13:43:52Z</ModuleTime>
<ModuleName>xunit.runner.utility.dotnet</ModuleName>
```

My Batch File:

```
@echo off

SET dotnet="C:/Program Files/dotnet/dotnet.exe" 
SET opencover=C:\Users\XXX\.nuget\packages\OpenCover\4.6.519\tools\OpenCover.Console.exe

SET targetargs="test c:\SfmcAdapter\trunk\dotnet_core\sfmc_adapter\test\SFMC.Adapter.Service.Tests"  
SET filter="+[*]*"  
SET coveragefile=Coverage.xml  
SET coveragedir=Coverage

REM Run code coverage analysis  
%opencover% -oldStyle -register:user -target:%dotnet% -output:%coveragefile% -targetargs:%targetargs% -filter:%filter% -skipautoprops -hideskipped:All
```

I want it to pick up my assembly coverage, not the xunit assemblies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out, make sure in the `project.json` file the `debugType` is set to full.  Then I was able to see the coverage.  Previously this was set to "portable".

```
 "debugType": "full"
```